# How to create function in jquery for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery

i try to create chat box close button , and i try to learn how to simplify my jquery function into **one dynamic function** you can check my jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/GUSVu/4/)

this is some code snippet :

```
//Close chat
$('.close1').click(function () {
    //do what ever you want here
    $('.wrap_box1').hide();
});

$('.close2').click(function () {
    //do what ever you want here
    $('.wrap_box2').hide();
});

$('.close3').click(function () {
    //do what ever you want here
    $('.wrap_box3').hide();
});
```

this script will loop maybe until 10 or 20 times so i hope i hav one function that can save minify this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use common class for p and a common class for div and relate respectively.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GUSVu/5/)**

*Html*

```
<p class='close'>Close 1</p>
<div class="wrap_box">Content here</div>
<p class='close'>Close 2</p>
<div class="wrap_box">Content here</div>
<p class='close'>Close 3</p>
<div class="wrap_box">Content here</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('.close').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.wrap_box').hide();
});
```

**Edit** Based on OP comments

You used the wrong class for bind the event and you also need find instead of next here

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GUSVu/14/)**

*Html*

```
<div class="wrap_box">
    <p class='close'>Close 1</p>Content here</div>
<div class="wrap_box">
    <p class='close'>Close 2</p>Content here</div>
<div class="wrap_box">
    <p class='close'>Close 3</p>Content here</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
$('.wrap_box').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.close').hide();
});
```

Comment: thanks, but why it's not working when i change the html like this http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/GUSVu/12/

Comment: Because you added <p> inside the <div> tag so it doesn't have any prev node

Comment: You used the wrong class for bind the event and you also need find instead of next here, http://jsfiddle.net/GUSVu/14/